# Redirect uri for access token refresh with the Google sample

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-client

I have coded my applicaton following [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#installed_applications) Gmail client example. It is creating an ephemeral server for handling the redirect uri:

```
 new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

For first time manual authorization by the user granting the permissions, the browser makes a callback to this server, at http://localhost/Callback. Since the docs say

> GoogleCredential takes care of automatically "refreshing" the token, which simply means getting a new access token

Without any redirect uri server up and running, how would it refresh the access token when it is about to expire?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#offline), you don't need the redirect uri for the refresh token.

Comment: How do I code my application when to get a new access token? i.e. how can I know just before it would expire?